# Can I avoid using mutex lock by implementing function as a class object method

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking, mutex

**Background:** I have a list of files in a location and `moveFile()` function that will be used to move these files. my goal is to move all those files in parallel. So, I implemented multiple threads.

To avoid conflict initially I considered mutex lock before `moveFile()`. That will prevent threads to run in parallel.

Here's how it's been implemented:

```
std::mutex mtx;
enum class status
{ SUCCESS, FAILED };

status moveFile()
{   //function implementation }

void fileOperator()
{   // This is prevent parallel operation 
    mtx.lock;
      moveFile();
    mtx.unlock;
} 

int main ()
{
  int threadSize= 3; //generic size
  std::thread fileProc[threadSize];
  int index = 0;

  // staring new threads
  for (index; index < threadSize; index++)
  {
    fileProc[index] = std::thread (&fileOperator);
  }

  //joining all the threads
  for (int i=0; i <threadSize; i++)
  {
    fileProc[i].join();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Suggestion:** I was wondering, if I remove mutex lock implement the `moveFile()` as in a class and call it as an object method, will it be a better way to implement parallel operation?

Comment: We would have to see what `moveFile()` does to let you know if it would be safe or not.

Comment: Nope, if you have multiple threads reading and writing the same resource, it doesn't matter whether or not that resource is a class - you will need a lock of some kind. Also, `std::thread fileProc[threadSize];` is not valid C++.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth it that case do I have any other option to process files parallely ?

Comment: If all what `fileOperator` does is a synchronized call to `moveFile`, then there will not be much parallelism in your program. Look inside `moveFile` to see where the actual shared resource is accessed, and guard these accesses.

Comment: You may not need a mutex at all, but it's not posible to tell from the code you have posted.

Comment: *"To avoid conflict..."* conflict with *what*? If the names of the files are unique, and distributed to distinctly unique threads (no file name is drafted by more than one thread), where would you expect a conflict to be encountered?

Comment: Re, "my goal is to move all those files in parallel." If those files are all on the same drive, then all of the reads and writes that accomplish the moves will have to go through the same, single hardware interface. You won't get any speedup, if that's what you were expecting, by having those commands issued by multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what the problem here is, most probably it's located in the moveFile function but something like this should work:

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

std::mutex mtx;

enum class status { SUCCESS, FAILED };

status moveFile() {
    std::cout << "Moving file" << std::endl;
    return status::SUCCESS;
}

void fileOperator() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    moveFile();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    int threadSize = 3;

    for (int index = 0; index < threadSize; ++index) {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&fileOperator));
    }

    for (auto& th : threads) {
        th.join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Could you also please post the contents of the moveFile to be able to help you with that? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the content of the moveFile. I will post if I can get a hand on it.

Comment: This is the same code as in question and you don't provide any answer here. You should have just left a comment if you wanted to ask the content of `moveFile`.